Mounting a doorway pullup/chinup bar on the wall above the doorway instead
I've had a Tunturi Deluxe Pullup Bar mounted in this doorway for many years and would really like it to be much higher (like 20 cm above the door moulding, almost so that the upper side touches the ceiling), so I've been reading some threads about people who mount their pullup bars to the studs. I've only read about people doing this with the bars that are actually designed for that, however.
There are three studs, one in the middle and one on each side of the doorway, and it's an old wooden house from the 1910's, with a wall that's 9 cm (3.5") thick (the door moulding is 11 cm). What if I'd screw 1" or 2" boards to the three studs with two screws in each board and stud, and then make the holes in the bar bigger and drill two new ones in the pullup bar so that I can mount it to said boards with these four holes, with 6" screws (2" through the bar's two components, i.e. the round "pipe" and the rectangular frame, and then 1-2" through the boards and then 2" into the stud)? I could even gain some support from the lip of the door moulding if I mount boards all the way down to it, I suppose.
Viable or stupid idea?
Edit: I drew the idea here, with the bar, doorway, studs, and proposed holes and bolts:



Further, you're asking us to assess the safety of modifying a purpose-built product. I'm not sure we're up to that without technical drawings of the thing. We'd have no way to know whether it would be catastrophically weakened. A TV mount is one thing. This is another.

Also, there are several questions here about mounting workout equipment in ways that it's not intended to be mounted, including, I think, some pull-up bars similar to yours. Have you searched here?

If you want a different pull-up bar, why does it have to be this one?  A fancy expensive one intended for a doorway with zero installation, when what you want is zero of that?

Sorry, I made a drawing now! The holes are in the part that was originally intended to be against the back of the wall, and are originally to hold the round bar to the rectangular thing, plus two more holes in the round bar. As for other ones, I haven't been able to find any by searching e.g. "pullup bar above doorway instead" and similar. And I wanted to do it with this one since I already have it, it makes it possible to do all variations that I want (not all do!) and it actually wasn't all that expensive - I bought it for the equivalent of 40 USD.

You're free to try, but this is off topic on this site. It's essentially furniture fabrication and not home improvement.

After reviewing the installation procedure it's clear that this device is not designed to carry load as you suggest. Mounting it by the upper rail and leaving the handles cantilevered away from the wall dramatically changes how force is carried through the curved tubes. It's likely to bend or break at the upper connections, which now have greatly multiplied leverage on them.

Does it help with the two extra holes in the curved bars below? Isn't it pretty much the same thing as the regular wall-mounted ones (e.g. https://5.imimg.com/data5/IV/HA/PY/SELLER-2739578/pull-up-wall-mount-chinup-bar.jpg)?

Holes in stressed members aren't a good idea. They don't really do anything for you there anyway. That one has heavy steel bracketry and diagonal bolstering underneath. Those aren't just for show.

In the standard doorway installation, the fulcrum is within the long horizontal tube. Your proposed wall-mount (good pic, btw) moves that fulcrum to the back uprights, meaning the lever arm you're pulling on is almost twice as long. The pipe is definitely not designed with that in mind. More holes in the pipe will not help.

It seems to me this type of pullup bar relies partly on friction forces (from the pads on the wall above the door, and end bars against the door side casings) and partly on the casing above the door, to keep it in place.  However, the friction forces only work because the mounting pad would be against the door header—otherwise the mounts would push through the drywall.  You might be able to get away with a 25-30 cm tall plywood panel that has another 20 cm plywood panel screwed/glued to it.  The taller side would be placed against the wall above the casing (think of it as a staircase).
ETA: Rough section sketch attached.


Yep, that's what I gathered as well - it's pushed against both the wall above the back of the doorway as well as against the sides of the door moulding simultaneously. Did you mean something like this? https://imgur.com/a/ZHrIkeE

Friction and the back bar hooking over the molding are what stop the bar from sliding straight down. This means that pulling down on the handles exerts a rotational force that tries to pivot the entire system around the point where it makes contact with the wall-- the long horizontal tube. Tube pushes down and away from you against the doorframe, and the back bar pushes up and towards you against the header. The system works because it converts much of your downward force into a twisting pinch against the solidly anchored doorframe. This wall-mount changes all of that, in not-helpful ways.

@JayMcEh how does it change that?  Which wall mount are you talking about here?

@Metalhead not sure about your sketch.  You got what I meant about the stepped plywood panel, at least.  What I mean is, take the panel and fasten it to the wall above the door molding on the "back" of the wall ("front" is the side of the wall where you hang from the bar).  Then install the bar using its traditional method, except instead of the flat horizontal bit resting on the door molding, it rests on the plywood step.

(I attached a rough sketch to my answer.)

@Huesmann I misunderstood, and assumed you were referring to something more like the drawing in the question itself. Your answer as pictured is both mechanically sound (the bar is unmodified and being used exactly as designed) and, I'd argue, a proper Home Improvement solution that's worth re-opening the question.
